# Determining if a function is surjective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Determine whether the following function is surjective: $f(x,y) = x^2-4$ where the function maps from $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$.

By plugging in numbers, I don't think this function is surjective because it only maps to the numbers $-4, -3, 0, 5, 12, ...$ Is this the only analysis needed to conclude whether this function is surjective. Also, is there some more formal method of saying whether $f(x,y)$ is surjective?

Comment: Only $x$ appears in your $f(x,y)$. Is it a typo? Moreover, to say a function is surjective or not, you must specify a _codomain_, which is not mentioned in your question at all.

Comment: The values of the function $f(x,y)$ do not seem to depend on $y$, only on $x$. Is this intentional?

Comment: $-4$ is also in the range.

Comment: @CaveJohnson Sorry, I updated the function.

Comment: @HansHüttel Yes, the function only depends on $x$.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f:X\to Y$ is **surjective** iff:

> the image of the domain $X$  completely covers the  codomain $Y$, i.e. $f(X)=Y$.

In your case you say that the domain is $X=\mathbb{Z}$. Note that this means that the function is a function of one variable $f(x)$ ( not $f(x,y)$), but if you does not specify the codomain $Y$ the function is not well defined, and we cannot know if the function is surjective or not.

If the codomain is $Y=\mathbb{Z}$, than , as you have noted, the function is not surjective.

Comment: I updated the function from mapping to $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$. Does this still hold?

Comment: Yes, adding the other variable does not change the value of the function, and also in this case the function is not surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Here, one must consult the definition of surjectivity. A function $f: A \rightarrow B$ is surjective if for every $b \in B$ there exists an $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$. To show that $f$ is surjective, we must show that this is the case. To show that $f$ is not surjective, it is enough to find a $b \in B$ such that there is no $a \in A$ where $f(a) = b$.

In this particular case: Is there a pair $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y) = 7$?